# 単語として切り出せる文字列に対して読み仮名を付与する場合に、指針となるようなPEPはありますか？

Tags: python, sphinx

■後日談

次の二つを分けて考えることにしました。

- 記法そのもの
- 記法も含めたかな文字情報を扱えるようにする拡張性

現在の実装は「 `よみ|漢字` の記法をそのまま維持して、同時に後者についてのサンプル実装も兼ねる」という位置付けにすることにしました。これを踏まえて `README.rst` を更新します。

---

Sphinx拡張を実装するにあたって思いついたことですが、内容の範囲としてはPythonになると思われるため、この二つをタグとしていいます。
よろしくお願いします。

■質問
単語として切り出せる文字列に対して、読み仮名を付与する場合に指針となるようなPEPはあるか？

■具体的には…
Sphinxにおいて、「.. index::」「.. glossary::」「:index:」で「単語/用語」という単位で文字列が記載されますが、この時に指定する文字列について「かな|単語」という方式で読み情報を付与する拡張を作りました。

問題なく動いていますが、将来的な対応についての留意点としてPyPIのページへの追記について悩んでいます。

■備考
現状は「この記法はPEPで規定されていない」かなぁ、と想像してます。

ズバリの情報がないにしても、今回のケースの場合のPEPの探索のセオリーやそのヒントがあれば嬉しいです。「そのような情報はないはず」という予想や、「近いものなら✕✕がそう」という周辺情報も受け付けています。

以上

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEPはありません。

reStructuredTextに関するPEPは https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/ がありますが、reStructuredTextの文法についてはほとんど触れられていません。

reStructuredTextの文法はdocutilsの公式ドキュメントが一時情報元になります。
しかし、index, glossaryといったディレクティブはSphinxが拡張したものです。
このため、indexに与える文字列の指針は、Sphinxのドキュメントに書いてなければ存在しない、ということになります。

「かな|単語」のような付加情報をどのような文法にするのかについては、PEPやSphinxドキュメントにないため、例えば「より一般的な他の似た記法に合わせておく」といった考え方で決めるしかないと思います。（といっても、ちょっと良い参考記法が思い付かないですが・・）